# Mouse skips in Mint

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I've just installed Linux Mint 13 (Cinnamon, 64big) and am enjoying it.  However, my mouse (which has been reliable for years on Windows) is no longer accurate.  It will skip around while I move it (Not a problem in normal usage, but irritating as all get out for small buttons or delicate copy/pastes)

I've played with the mouse settings (sensitivity/acceleration), but that didn't change anything.  I'm using a Logitech G5 mouse.

Comment: It looks like a sensitivity problem, can be adjusted in mouse config.

Answer (score 1):

There should be drivers available for Logitech G5. Here's a [link](http://mikebeach.org/2010/06/27/logitech-devices-on-ubuntu-linux-and-others/) to get you started.

Comment: There is drivers for Logitech in kernel side, especially for bluetooth mouses.